# How to add nodes to Dagre layout with Cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am trying to add nodes to a dagre graph through cityscape.js. The problem is that the nodes are not painted. 
This is the code that I currently have:

```
cy.add({
      group: "nodes",
      data: { id:"n0",name:"n0",weight: 75 },
  });
  $.ajax(url).done(function(jsonTree){
      var newNodes=[];
      for(var i=1;i<6;i++){
        //var child = jsonTree.result[i];
        newNodes.push(
          { group: "nodes", data: { id: "n"+i, name:"n"+i}},
          { group: "edges", data: { id: "e"+i, source: "n0", target: "n"+i } }
        );

      }
      cy.add(newNodes);
```

Any ideas? I have used loaded function to reload the graph but it does not work. I do not know if i have to use a specific function to reload the graph.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add positions for the new nodes. From the [cytoscape.js docs](http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/graph-manipulation/cy.add):

> It is important to note that the positions of newly added nodes must
>   be defined when calling cy.add(). Nodes can not be placed in the graph
>   without a valid position — otherwise they could not be displayed.

You'll want something like this for the `for` loop:

```
  var newNodes=[];
  for(var i=1;i<6;i++){
     newNodes.push(
          { group: "nodes", 
              data: { 
                id: "n"+i, 
                name:"n"+i
              },
           //this is the bit you missed: position
              position: {
               x:25*i,
               y:20*i
              }
           },
          { group: "edges", 
           data: { 
             id: "e"+i, 
             source: "testnode", 
             target: "n"+i 
           } 
          }
        );
      }
  cy.add(newNodes);
```

[Here's a JSBin showing a graph with new nodes added dynamically](https://jsbin.com/hugati/edit?js,output)